# PyQt Как построить дерево QTreeView по данным из базы данных

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtreeview

Я получаю данные из БД. Данные уже отсортированы, и сначала идет родительский узел, а затем, если есть, дочерний узел. Я получаю данные в этой форме (id, parent_id, уровень, имя, описание, create_at, updated_at):

```
tree = [(2, 1, 1, 'parent 1', None, None, None), (5, 'child 1 - 1', 2, 2, None, None, None), (6, 'child 1 - 2', 2, 2, None, None, None), (9, 'child 1- 3', 2, 2, None, None, None), (7, 'child 1 - 1 - 1', 5, 3, None, None, None), (11, 'children 2- 1', 6, 3, '', '2019-12-08 18:39:26.395679', '2019-12-08 18:39:26.395679'), (10, 'child 4 levl parent 1', 7, 4, None, None, None), (3, 1, 1, 'parent 2', None, None, None), (13, 'parent 2- 1 - chil', 3, 2, '', '2019-12-08 18:44:34.458328', '2019-12-08 18:44:34.458328'), (4, 1, 1, 'parent 3', None, None, None), (8, 1, 1, 'parent 4', None, None, None)]
```

Подскажите, как построить дерево, в котором при клике на элементы этого дерева, передается `ID` элемента? Это максимум, что получилось. Я привел данные из БД к такому словарю, дерево строится верно, но при клике я не знаю как получить `ID` элемента (и как его задать в такой структуре):

```
    tree = {'parent 1': {'child 1 - 1': {'child 1 - 1 - 1': {'child 4 levl parent 1': {}}}, 'child 1 - 2': {'children 2- 1': {}}, 'child 1- 3': {}}, 'parent 2': {'parent 2- 1 - chil': {}}, 'parent 3': {}, 'parent 4': {}}

def treeRubrics(self):
    self.treeList = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
    self.treeList.setObjectName("treeList")
    self.treeList.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 0))
    self.treeList.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 16777215))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.treeList, 3, 0, 1, 1)
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    self.populateTree(self.tree, model.invisibleRootItem())
    self.treeList.setModel(model)
    model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Records tree')
    self.treeList.expandAll()
    self.treeList.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.onSelectionChanged)
    __sortingEnabled = self.treeList.isSortingEnabled()
    self.treeList.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
```

Подскажите, как мне переделать код, что бы создать дерево вида https://clip2net.com/s/454EMMc и для каждого пункта задать свой ID, а потом при клике на пункт - возвращать ID? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

# tree = {'parent 1': {'child 1 - 1': {'child 1 - 1 - 1': {'child 4 levl parent 1': {}}}, 'child 1 - 2': {'children 2- 1': {}}, 'child 1- 3': {}}, 'parent 2': {'parent 2- 1 - chil': {}}, 'parent 3': {}, 'parent 4': {}}
# vvv см. ниже

tree = {
    'parent 1': {
        'child 1 - 1': {
            'child 1 - 1 - 1': {
                'child 4 levl parent 1': {}
            }
        },
    },                                              # ++
    ## 
    'child 1 - 2': {
        'children 2- 1': {}
    }, 
    #             +
    'child 1- 3': {                                 # - {}
    }, 
    'parent 2': {
        'parent 2- 1 - chil': {}
    }, 
    'parent 3': {}, 
    'parent 4': {}
}



class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tree_view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tree_view)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.populateTree(tree, model.invisibleRootItem())
        self.tree_view.setModel(model)
        model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Записи')
        self.tree_view.expandAll()
        self.tree_view.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.onSelectionChanged)

    def populateTree(self, children, parent):
        for child in children:
            child_item = QtGui.QStandardItem(child)
            parent.appendRow(child_item)
            if isinstance(children, dict):
                self.populateTree(children[child], child_item)

    def onSelectionChanged(self, *args):
        for sel in self.tree_view.selectedIndexes():
            val = "/"+sel.data()
            while sel.parent().isValid():
                sel = sel.parent()
                val = "/"+ sel.data()+ val
            print(val)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @PetrSklyarov что не так ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeView, QApplication


class MyTree(QTreeView):
    def currentChanged(self, current: QtCore.QModelIndex, previous: QtCore.QModelIndex) -> None:
        print(self.model().data(current, Qt.UserRole))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

model = QStandardItemModel()
root = QStandardItem('root')
root.setData('root item idx', Qt.UserRole)
model.appendRow(root)
item1 = QStandardItem('item1')
item1.setData(1, Qt.UserRole)
item2 = QStandardItem('item2')
item2.setData(2, Qt.UserRole)
root.appendRow(item1)
root.appendRow(item2)

tree = MyTree()
tree.setModel(model)
tree.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Ключевые строки:

```
item1.setData(1, Qt.UserRole)
self.model().data(current, Qt.UserRole)
```